# AWS services down monitors

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticache

I am new to AWS monitors, so this might be a naive question. I was just checking if there are any monitors that will tell us if the AWS services are down? For example if ElasticSearch, or ElastiCache is down, Is there a way to create an alarm? Are there are any Metrics available for them? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fairly new feature called [AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-personal-health-dashboard-status-you-can-relate-to/) that allows you to track if your account is experiencing any service outages. You can setup notifications in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Those are at the AWS level as in if AWS service is down. Is there a way to find out if any of my app/service is down. Is it possible to catch the errors through cloudwatch?

Comment: Monitoring AWS services is what is sounded like you were looking for. The various AWS services you use will of course post metrics to CloudWatch. In addition, you can have your applications publish custom metrics: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

That link will get you pretty much all you need to see what is up and down, but yes you can also set up cloudwatch monitors and notifications to be alerted (or take some action), if specific problems come up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Those are at the AWS level as in if AWS service is down. Is there a way to find out if any of my app/service is down. Is it possible to catch the errors through cloudwatch?